# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':launcher:releaseRuntimeClasspath' Unity

Tags: c#, android, api, unity-game-engine, sdk

After adding advertisement to `_game_` scene I faced a lot of problems not for first week. I searched about all these problems in Google.Some problems I could resolve, some are not.But about this error I can't find correct information.

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.plugin:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild FAILED
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible >with Gradle 7.0.
> Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
> See >https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:com>mand_line_warnings
> 5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) `

**Also appeared this axception:**

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':launcher:preReleaseBuild'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration
> ':launcher:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Resolved 'android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'android.arch.core:common:1.1.1' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Did not resolve 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.0.0' which is part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Did not resolve 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.0.0' which is part of the dependency lock state
> Did not resolve 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0' which is part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1' which is not part of the dependency lock state
> Resolved 'com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0' which is not part of the dependency lock state

> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -->debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights

> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 2s
> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)`

**I tried:**

- Make some changes in External Tools>Android(I'm using all standart tools provided by Unity excluded JDK files(I downloaded it))
- Tried to build project with IL2CPP - Same Error
- In Publishing Settings > Build checked all the marks except last two
- I'm using a keystore in my project
- Target API level is Highest Installed

I think the proplem is with `Did not resolve 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.0.0' which is part of the dependency lock state`.

Can you kind people halp mw whith this?